# Async and await execution issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

[image: Code Image]

Why the output is like this?

```
123
XYZ
```

As per my understanding, it should print XYZ first, as I am not writing await in line no. 50

Comment: You see those wiggly lines under your `Test1()` and `Test()`? Hover your mouse over them; they tell you something really important.

Comment: Aman could you edit the question and replace the "Code image" with the same code in text format?

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep` waits synchronously. Your thread simply stops there for 10 seconds, since there's nothing telling it to go back to the caller. Try `await Task.Delay(10_000)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need set PrintDate method => public static async void and on her body set => await Test1(); because Test1 method was async